# Check if file exists - C programming

Tags: c

I've had trouble trying to create this function that takes users input and checks if the file exists or not. I keep on getting warning messages (format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'const char **') every time I try to run the code.

I've tried to declare the variable fileName in different ways but it still seems to not be working. So I'm curious to know if I'm using access wrong or if it's even possible to use when taking user input.

```
int readFunc(const char *fileName) {
    printf("Search for file: ");
    scanf("%s", &fileName);

    if(access(fileName, F_OK) == 0) {
        menuFunc();
    } else {
        printf("File doesn't exist!\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", &fileName);` -> `scanf("%s", fileName);`

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Please do not use `access(2)` to test if a file exists: that's not what it's for.  It's intended only for setuid/setgid programs that look at whether the underlying user - not the effective user - has access to the file. Use the `stat(2)` system call instead.

Comment: @kaylum That won't really help, considering `fileName` is `const`.

Comment: Why you're `scanf`-ing into that argument in the first place makes no sense, either design-wise or langauge-wise.  Turn up your compiler warnings and treat them as errors, because passing a `const char *` to a call that expects `char*` is a recipe for disaster. Don't try and make this function a swiss army knife.

Comment: @AdrianMole True. Though technically it will help cause it will get rid of that error :-) Yeah, it's not clear that that `scanf` is needed at all.

Comment: @kaylum Actually, all it does is remove one `*` from the warning message. :-)

Comment: I was being silly. I meant that specific error will be gone and replaced by a different error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the C programming language had a string data type, the following lines of code would be correct:

> ```
> string fileName;
> scanf("%s", &fileName);
> ```

However, the C programming language does not have a string data type, but strings must be stored in arrays of characters.

The `char *` data type does **not** hold a complete string, but it holds a "pointer" to an array. This means: The data type holds a reference to an array where the string is stored.

Let's say we use a self-written variant of `scanf()` named `myScanf()`:

```
const char * fileName;
myScanf("%s", &fileName);
```

In this example the function `myScanf()` returns a "pointer" to a string. This means: The function stores the string in some array and then returns the reference ("pointer") to that array in the variable `fileName`.

The problem is: Because the function `scanf()` does not know which array should be used to store the string, **you** have to provide this array.

This means: `scanf()` does **not return** a pointer to an array (unlike `"&d"`, which returns a number), but `scanf()` takes a pointer to an array (to the array where you want `scanf()` to store the string) as **input argument**:

```
int a;
char *b;
...
scanf("%d", &a); /* a is an output from scanf() */
scanf("%s", b); /* b is an input to scanf() */
```

However, the following line will also not work:

> ```
> scanf("%s", fileName);
> ```

You tell `scanf()` to overwrite the array that has been passed as argument to the `readFunc()` function; and the `const` specifier says, that the function `readFunc()` must not overwrite this array!

You have to specify your own array where the file name is stored:

```
char fileName2[300]; /* Maximum 300-1 characters */
...
scanf("%s", fileName2);
...
access(fileName2, F_OK);
```

Note that C cannot really pass arrays to functions as arguments.

Instead, it automatically creates a "pointer" (a reference, data type `char *`) to the array if you write something like `access(fileName2 ...)`.